# I can't fetch query parameters ($_GET parameters) with get_query_var

Tags: php, plugin-development, pagination, query-variable

I am developing pagination for a list of posts in my plugin. I've added a custom parameter in my `plugin_functions.php` file:

```
add_query_arg('pworkspage', 1);
```

As you can see it defaults to "1". Now, whenever I visit the custom admin page of my plugin with that parameter in the URL (`www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mycustompage&pworkspage=2`) my script can't see the parameter at all.

I am retrieving the parameter like this:

```
$page_nr = get_query_var('pworkspage', 1);
```

The variable `$page_nr` is equal to `string(0) ""`.

I tried a different approach using the `query_vars` filter but I got the same results.

**Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Read: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Notes

Comment: Read: my post entirely - "I tried a different approach using the query_vars filter but I got the same results". It doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query vars are for use in the main `$wp_query` query object, your custom admin page has no main query, so no vars are parsed into a query object that can be accessed via `get_query_var`. I don't think there's anything WordPress-specific that can be used in this case, I would just access the value via `$_GET`.

Comment: Yep, best bet is to ignore WordPress on your own custom page.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That's very informative. I think that the WordPress codex should be updated with your answer. Are there any tips about sanitizing $_GET parameters that are going to be used in that place?

Comment: The [Data Validation Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) has a lot of useful info on that subject.